# How to set the urls to address a file in views.py?

Tags: django

I cannot render the contact.html. Why? I am facing to the following error and description:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
admin/
[name='index']
contact [name='contact']
The current path, contact/, didn't match any of these.
Here is my code:

#### views.py

```py
    def contact(request):

        if request.method == 'POST' :
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)   
            if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return render ('thanks.html', {'form':form})    
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form':form})
```

#### models.py

```py
    from django.db import models

    class Contact (models.Model):
        name = models.CharField (max_length=100)
        email = models.EmailField (max_length=100)
        subject = models.CharField (max_length=100)
        message = models.TextField (max_length=1000)
```

#### forms.py

```py
    from django.forms import ModelForm  
    from .models import ContactModel

    class ContactForm (ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ContactModel
            fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message']
```

#### urls.py

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'), 
        path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    ]
```

#### contact.html

```html
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <br />

        <form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}

          ...

          <div id="success">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
                 id="sendMessageButton">
                 Send Message
             </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1) Probably means the form is not valid, are you rendering validations errors? 2) You should be redirecting after a POST to stop a user accidentally submitting the form again if they refresh the page

Comment: might work your code but you render the same template code at contact and thanks. check out your template

Comment: Bob, That was a typo. I removed the thanks-template. It simply displays the form-data: name, email, subject and message.

Comment: You should show the rest of the contact template.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the form is valid? Repeating the Contact-page indicates that you end up within the `else:`. That would explain why nothing is saved, as the `if:` is skipped, and it would explain why the incorrect `render()` without a request passed is not giving you any issues.

Try printing out the POST-data with `print(request.POST)` at the top of the view to see if all variables you expect to see are there and that everything is spelled correctly (easy mistake). Compare what is POST:ed with what your form is looking for.

When you get that working, I would consider changing the `render` to a `redirect`.

It is also a good idea to add a second `else:` if the form is not valid. This would look like:

```
if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        form.save()
        return redirect('your-thankyou-url')

else: #if form is not valid
    render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

That would render any errors and make it clear for whomever is entering information that something submitted is faulty.

Best of luck!